# How to recover messages from failed transaction in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: kotlin, activemq-artemis

```
val connectionFactory = ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url)
val connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()
val session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED)
val destination = session.createQueue("example.queue")

val producer = session.createProducer(destination)

// Maintain a list of messages sent within the transaction
val messagesInTransaction = mutableListOf<Message>()

// Send a batch of messages within a transaction
val numMessagesToSend = 10
for (i in 1..numMessagesToSend) {
    val message = session.createTextMessage("Hello, World! ($i)")
    producer.send(message)
    messagesInTransaction.add(message)
}

// Commit the transaction
try {
    session.commit()
    println("Transaction committed successfully")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // Roll back the transaction and retry sending the messages
    session.rollback()
    println("Transaction rolled back: $e")
    
    for (message in messagesInTransaction) {
        println("Retrying sending message: $message")
        producer.send(message)
    }
}

// Close the JMS resources
producer.close()
session.close()
connection.close()
```

I found this kotlin code that uses List to get all messages in transaction and if the commit fails and we go to the catch block we use that list as the recovered messages of our failed transaction and resend them again.
Is this the best practice to recover messages from the failed transaction ?

I Also read an article about the rollback method says that when the transaction fails the messages stored in the sender's message buffer. How so ? and can u give me an example of recovering that message buffer ?

Comment: This question should be closed on a few different grounds. First, the question about "best practice" is inherently opinion-based. Every use-case has unique constraints, and what is "best" in any give situation is up for debate. Second, you're asking too many questions here. Aside from the question about "best practice" you're asking about an article you read somewhere apparently about some implementation details of the client you're using. Each question should focus on a single issue. You've got multiple, independent questions here.

Comment: It's also worth noting that "recovery" already has a common usage in the context of transactions involving XA (i.e. 2-phase commit protocol). For example, when an XA transaction fails between the prepare and commit phases and needs to be "recovered" by the originating transaction manager. Your question isn't really about "recovering" a transaction as it is about _retrying_ it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm working on a project that gets rows from db table,  create a message for each row and send them to the broker and then delete these rows from the table. How to manage the case of failed transaction without loosing the data ?

Comment: Mitigating data loss with a transaction between two resources is a completely different question from the ones you've already asked in your question. Create a new question about this or rewrite your existing question.